# ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable while Creating a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi guys I intend to create a Trigger for MySQL table so that after Values are Inserted into the table, the Column `exp_sales` is set to `qnty_received` value *selling_price but I am getting this error:

> ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'exp_sales'

This is My Query:

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger tsales after insert on Store_info_table
for each row
set exp_sales = qnty_received * selling_price;
END$$
```

What is the problem and what is the best way to create the trigger so that after teh Quantity and selling Price is Inserted, the field for `exp_sales(Total)` is Updated with the right value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right you want to update a field of your record after insert. Try

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger tsales after insert on Store_info_table
for each row
begin
    UPDATE Store_info_table 
    SET exp_sales = NEW.qnty_received * NEW.selling_price
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 2):

If I unserstand corrctly `exp_sales` is a column name you want to update:

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger tsales after insert on Store_info_table
for each row
    update Store_info_table
    set exp_sales = NEW.qnty_received * NEW.selling_price
    where id = NEW.id;
END$$
```

better approach would be to use [INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table_name(...)VALUES(...) 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY SET exp_sales = qnty_received * selling_price;
```

Comment: I got this Exception `java.sql.SQLException: Can't update table 'Store_info_table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: It's not possible to update same table inside trigger written on same table. Alternatively you can try second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you forgotten about the NEW keyword?

Try this one -

```
SET NEW.exp_sales = NEW.qnty_received * NEW.selling_price;
```

But, I think you should not do this, because you always can calculate 'total' value in SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it works for me

```
create trigger tsales
after insert
on
Store_info_table
for each row
set new.exp_sales = new.qnty_received * new.selling_price;
```

but since you want the exp_sales calculated automatically, why would you not use `before` instead of `after`?